# Contact Form - Send / Receive issues

Tags: php, html

I have coded a contact form , but for some reason I am not actually getting the email , but the php code has no errors and the form returns a success message. I have removed my email address from the code here.

**Contact form**

```
<body>
<div class='formbody'>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<form id="contact-form" action="send.php" method="POST">

  <p>Hi</p>
  <p>My
    <label for="your-name">name</label> is
    <input type="text" name="your-name" id="your-name" minlength="3" placeholder="(your name here)" required> and</p>

  <p>my
    <label for="email">email address</label> is
    <input type="email" name="your-email" id="email" placeholder="(your email address)" required>
  </p>

  <p> I have a
    <label for="your-message">message</label> for you,</p>

  <p>
    <textarea name="your-message" id="your-message" placeholder="(your msg here)" class="expanding" required></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">
      <svg version="1.1" class="send-icn" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 100 36" enable-background="new 0 0 100 36" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M100,0L100,0 M23.8,7.1L100,0L40.9,36l-4.7-7.5L22,34.8l-4-11L0,30.5L16.4,8.7l5.4,15L23,7L23.8,7.1z M16.8,20.4l-1.5-4.3
    l-5.1,6.7L16.8,20.4z M34.4,25.4l-8.1-13.1L25,29.6L34.4,25.4z M35.2,13.2l8.1,13.1L70,9.9L35.2,13.2z" />
      </svg>
      <small>SEND PLEASE</small>
    </button>
  </p>
</form>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bs-animation.js"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**send.php**

```
    <?php 
$page='contactus';
include('header.php');
include('navbar.php');

?>

<?php
$to = 'removed';
$name = TRIM (stripslashes($_POST['your-name']));
$email = TRIM (stripslashes($_POST['your-email']));
$message = TRIM (stripslashes($_POST['your-message']));
$subject = 'Message';


$name = 'Name: ';
$email= 'From:';
$message= 'Message: ';





if( mail($to, $subject, $name , $email , $message) ){
        echo 'success';

}

else{

    print('There has been a small error . Sorry!!');
}

?>
```

Comment: Mail function always follow this rule mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);

Comment: Ok , not quite sure what you mean.? Can you elaborate please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you haven't sent your headers or added headers in here.

So rather than passing the form to a new file (send.php) we add the logic to send.php and have the form file require it at the top of your code as shown below:

```
<?php

require 'send.php';

$send = new sendEmail();
?>

<body>
<div class='formbody'>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['sendForm']))
    {
        $send->sendMail($_POST['your-name'], $_POST['your-email'], $_POST['your-message']);
    }
    ?>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <form id="contact-form" action="" method="post">

        <p>Hi</p>
        <p>My
            <label for="your-name">name</label> is
            <input type="text" name="your-name" id="your-name" minlength="3" placeholder="(your name here)" required> and</p>

        <p>my
            <label for="email">email address</label> is
            <input type="email" name="your-email" id="email" placeholder="(your email address)" required>
        </p>

        <p> I have a
            <label for="your-message">message</label> for you,</p>

        <p>
            <textarea name="your-message" id="your-message" placeholder="(your msg here)" class="expanding" required></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" name="sendForm">
                <svg version="1.1" class="send-icn" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 100 36" enable-background="new 0 0 100 36" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M100,0L100,0 M23.8,7.1L100,0L40.9,36l-4.7-7.5L22,34.8l-4-11L0,30.5L16.4,8.7l5.4,15L23,7L23.8,7.1z M16.8,20.4l-1.5-4.3
    l-5.1,6.7L16.8,20.4z M34.4,25.4l-8.1-13.1L25,29.6L34.4,25.4z M35.2,13.2l8.1,13.1L70,9.9L35.2,13.2z" />
      </svg>
                <small>SEND PLEASE</small>
            </button>
        </p>
    </form>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bs-animation.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then within the send.php file you'd add:

```
<?php

class sendEmail
{
    public function sendMail($name, $email, $message)
    {
        if (!empty($name))
        {
            if (!empty($email))
            {
                if (!empty($message))
                {
                    $email_to = 'YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS';
                    $header = 'From: ' . $name ."<noreply@yourdomain.co.uk/com>". "\r\n" .
                        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                    @mail($email_to, 'Enquiry Received', 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n\r\n". 'Email: ' .$email. "\r\n\r\n". 'Message: ' .$message."\r\n\r\n", $header);

                    echo "Thanks for contacting us";

                } else {
                    echo "Please enter a message";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Please provide your email address.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Please provide your name.";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Now, I have added conditions that if a field is empty it'll return an error, this is solely because the `required` added into the input fields can be bypassed so it's always good to have conditions set up too.

**Note:** You can also add logic into here if you ever wished to store form enquiries etc into your database such as sent from whatever IP address, time it was sent, who it was from, what the message says.

This is just a basic example but you'll see whats been done once reading the code.

Comment: OP does not use a class in his question,

Comment: The OP doesn't have to use the class but it's the better practiced route. Not worth the negative vote in my opinion for trying to guide the OP the correct way with PHP.

Comment: The DV not mine, I don't dv answers instead I add when there's a need to]

Comment: Thank you and answered clean and to the point. Appreciate the help. All working now.  Thank you